# PHP/MySQL table search by Perl

Tags: php, mysql, perl

With not understanding perl/MySQL enough I’m hoping someone here can give a helping hand.
The code obviously doesn't work, but it's what I have so far and I'm still learning.

I’m wanting to open and search a database for the `$ticket_id` obtained from a php page and get one or both of either the email address and/or phone email if one is there for that `$ticket_id`. There will be at least one.

Since I seem to be asked this every once a while. (This is not a school project. I’ve been out of school since 75).

I have the script working with out the database lookup of the information but I have to hand code each setup with the ticket_id and email address(s). Glad I only have 5 people using this, but have been getting asked by others that would like to use it. So I think this would be a good time to stream line the process to use a MySQL database that way if I ever got busy with it, I wouldn’t have to work to much beyond filling out a form page to add their info.

In the database needing to search there is 3 tables, I need to search for the ticket_id and then get the username that is their email address and/or the phone-email but either could be empty depending on the type of notice they want.

This can be changed anyway needed. It only has one record in it to work with this new setup.

```
username:  email(at)address(dot)com
ticket_id: 1-YS25UHRN3N9D
phone: 1234567890(at)cellphone(dot)com
```

I was told this could be done with JavaScript window.onload so changing HTML page to PHP would not be needed but don’t know JavaScript at all.

The echo script might be wrong. `$pg` is received fine by the script at this time with no `echo` of it needed.

Top of PHP page

```
<?php
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Client IP address
  $pg = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // What page did they view
  $ticket_id = '1-YS25UHRN3N9D'; // Ticket id
  $message = '1'; // 1=email, 2=text, 3=email & text
  $url = "/cgi-bin/log_it.cgi"; // back-end url
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $url . '?id=' . $id . '&amp;ip=' . $ip 
.  '?ticket_id=' . $ticket_id . ' . '?message=' . $message . '"></script>';
?>
```

I was told putting the database login information in the cgi was bad, but I don’t know how to work it into a php file and access the file from perl or other way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W

use CGI;
use CGI param;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;

# database
$host = "localhost";
$database = "users";
$tablename = "tickets";
$user = "username";
$pw = "password";

# Obtain $id & $ip from web page.
$id = param("ticket_id");
$ip = param("ip");

# message
# 1 = email
# 2 = phone
# 3 = both
$message = param("message");

# Connect to database
$connect = Mysql->connect($host, $database, $user, $pw);

# DB
$connect->selectdb($database);

# MySQL QUERY
$myquery = "SELECT ticket_id FROM user";

# QUERY
$myquery = "SELECT ticket_id FROM $tablename";

# Need to be worked on.
# If record not found.
#
#  "To Do" send a page or popup if the id is not valid.
#    $file = "/var/log/invalid_id_iptrace.txt";
#    open(FILE, ">$file");
#   print FILE strftime("%A %B %d, %Y - %I:%M %p %Z\n", localtime(time) );
#    print FILE " -- IP Address: $ip\n\t Accessed unknown $id:\n------\n";
#    close(FILE);
#    system("mail -s 'Page visited Unknown' admin\@mydomain.com \< /var/log
#    /invalid_id_iptrace.txt");
# exit();

#check if we have a matching $id == $ticket_id
if ($id =~ /$ticket_id/) {

 #if we have a match open the file to write.
 $file = "/var/log/$ticket_id_iptrace.txt";
 open(FILE, ">$file");

 # lets put the time in the file.
 print FILE strftime("%A %B %d, %Y - %I:%M %p %Z\n", localtime(time) );

 # put the IP address and web page visited.
 print FILE " -- IP Address: $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}\n\t Accessed your page:
 $ENV{HTTP_REFERER}\n------\n";
 print FILE " -- Here is the IP information we found:\n------\n";

 #close the file. Finished with the first part
 close(FILE);

 # Run the IP2Location script.
 system("./iptrace.sh $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR} json city>>/var/log/$ticket_id_iptrace.txt");

 # Lets send an email and or text with all the information.

 # Send email
 if($message =~ /1/) {
  system("mail -s 'Web Page visited' $username \< /var/log/$ticket_id_iptrace.txt");
 }

 # Send text
 if($message =~ /2/) {
  system("mail -s 'Web Page visited' $phone \< /var/log/$ticket_id_iptrace.txt");
 }

 # Send email and text message
 if($message =~/3/) {
  system("mail -s 'Web Page visited' $username \< /var/log/$ticket_id_iptrace.txt");
  system("mail -s 'Web Page visited' $phone \< /var/log/$ticket_id_iptrace.txt");
 }
 exit();
 }

exit();
#end of script
```

Thank you

**Update:** Second (cleaned up) version of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI qw/param/;
use DBI();

# database
my $host = "remotehost";
my $database = "database";
my $tablename = "table";
my $user = "user";
my $pw = "pwd";

# Obtain $id & $ip from web page.
my $id = param("id");
my $ip = param("ip");
my $ticket_id = "ticket_id";
my $file = "/tmp/_iptrace.txt";
my $fileb = "/tmp/invalid_id_iptrace.txt";
my $fh = "FILE";
my $phone = "phone";
my $username = "username";
# message
# 1 = email
# 2 = phone
# 3 = both
my $message = param("message");

# Connect to database
my $connect = Mysql->connect($host, $database, $user, $pw);

# DB
$connect->selectdb($database);

 # QUERY
my $myquery = "SELECT ticket_id FROM $tablename";

# EXECUTE
my $execute = $connect->query($myquery);

#check if we have a matching $id == $ticket_id
if ($id == $payer_id) {
#if we have a match open the file to write.
open(my $fh, '>', $file) or die $!;

# lets put the time in the file.
print $fh strftime("%A %B %d, %Y - %I:%M %p %Z\n", localtime(time) );

# put the IP address and web page visited.
print $fh " -- IP Address: $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}\n\t Accessed your page:
    $ENV{HTTP_REFERER}\n------\n";
print $fh " -- Here is the information we found:\n------\n";

#close the file. Finished with the first part
close($fh);

# Run the IP2Location script.
system("./iptrace.sh $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR} json city>>/tmp/$ticket_id$file");

# Lets send an email and or text with all the information.
# Send email
    if($message == 1) {
    system("mail -s 'Web Page visited' $username \< /tmp/$ticket
            _id$file");
    }
    # Send text
    if($message == 2) {
    system("mail -s 'Web Page visited' $phone \< /tmp/$ticket
            _id$file");
}
# Send email and text message
if($message == 3) {
    system("mail -s 'Web Page visited' $username \< /tmp/$ticket
            _id$file");
    system("mail -s 'Web Page visited' $phone \< /tmp/$ticket
            _id$file");
    }
exit();
}
#  "To Do" send a page or popup if the id is not valid.

open($fh, ">$fileb");
print $fh strftime("%A %B %d, %Y - %I:%M %p %Z\n", localtime(time) );
print $fh " -- IP Address: $ip\n\t Accessed unknown $id:\n------\n";
close($fh);
system("mail -s 'Page visited Unknown' admin\@mydomain.com \<
/tmp/invalid_id_iptrace.txt");

exit();
#end of script
```

Comment: Why dont you just do all this on the PHP side? why are you using the cgi script? And why invoke it with JS... you should just use curl from the php side.

Comment: @prodigitalson Because having user copy and paste anything more than 6 lines is prone to errors. I had to do it for 2 out of 5. If I allow others to use the setup I don't want them having everything on their web sites. The php was given to me by someone. So your asking a question I don't have an answer for.

Comment: So this all runs on a single server or across multiple servers? What is the language you are best with?

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a question in your post. You say "the code obviously doesn't work", but you don't tell us what kind on unexpected behaviour you're seeing. So here are some comments on your code. One of them might address the issue.

1/ It should be '-w' on the shebang line, not '-W'. In fact these days you should just remove '-w' and include `use warnings;` just below the shebang line.

2/ You should also add `use strict;` just below `use warnings;`. This will appear to completely break your program as it will insist on you predeclaring all of your variables - which you do using `my` (`my $host = 'localhost'`, etc). This will be a pain at first, but it's a really good habit to get into.

3/ You only need one `use CGI` line. And it should be `use CGI qw/param/;`.

4/ You're using a class called Mysql. But you don't load that class anywhere. Where does that class come from? You should really be using a combination of [DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) and [DBD::mysql](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3amysql).

5/ You put an SQL query into `$mysquery` but then you immediately overwrite it with another one. That's not going to cause an error - it's probably just a indication of some confusion on your part.

6/ Your `if ($id =~ /$ticket_id/)` is almost certainly better written as `if ($id == $ticket_id)`. No need to use regular expressions if you're just comparing two numbers.

7/ You should really check the return value from your call to `open`.

```
open(FILE, ">$file") or die $!;
```

In fact, I'd rewrite that to use 3-arg open and an autovivified filehandle.

```
open(my $fh, '>', $file) or die $!;
```

You'll then need to change `FILE` to `$fh` throughout the code.

8/ Again, your three comparisons against `$message` can just be simple `==` matches rather than using regex matching.

If you're going to be doing a lot of this, then I really recommend reading a good book like "Learning Perl" or "Beginning Perl".

Comment: Without seeing the cleaned up code I can't really help. Perhaps you can post the current code as an update to the original post.

Comment: Although I will point out that Perl's error messages usually make a lot of sense if you just take the time to read them carefully. And when they don't, try adding `use diagnostics` to the code.

Comment: When posting the cleaned up version of the code, it's good practice to add it to the end of the post rather than overwriting the original version. That way, other people's comments don't look wrong. I've edited your post to correct this.

Comment: If your ticket ID is a string rather than a number then you'll need to  use `eq` instead of `==`.

Comment: If you switch to using DBI/DBD::mysql instead of Mysql.pm then you'll need to change the way you connect to the database. See the DBI documentation for details.

Comment: If you're comparing numbers use `$var1 == $var2`. If you're comparing strings use `$var1 eq $var2`. If you're matching against patterns (which you're not, so you don't need this) use `$var1 =~ /$var2/`.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be outputting any headers. In fact it doesn't seen to be outputting anything to STDOUT. That will be why you're seeing that error. A CGI program should return something to the browser. At the very least, you should take the time to understand how CGI interactions work. Ovid's course is a great introduction - http://ovid-cgi-course.perl-begin.org/cgi-course/

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's sending all the information by email, just the invalid id notice. It doesn't seem to be reading the database information. This was a crazy idea and way out of my league to think I'd be able to do something like this and taking up to much time here. Thanks for all you've done. Please help someone that has a critical need.

Comment: Ok. That's really bizarre. Bob has deleted all of his comments here and left me looking like I've bene talking to myself :-/